# Taking user input to Google Sheets using Apps Script and process with queries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I created a spreadsheet for reporting students attendance that contains 8 sheets (each sheet named as a subject code). After completing a particular class, I go to the specific sheet (subject) and select all the rows of that particular date and press the button `AfterClass-->Process Data` (sorting, removing duplicates and protecting) using Google Apps Script/Macros. All working fine.

Now I created a DASHBOARD and I want that a teacher can do everything from the dashboard rather than going to individual sheet (subject). S/he can give two inputs - subject (sheetname) and Date from the Dashboard and then automatically process these specific dataset of that Sheet (Not all data of the sheet). Please note that date is in Column A and subject-code in Column F. The code I wrote as follows:

```
  function AfterClass() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //Sorting and removing duplicates
  var height = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getHeight();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, height, 6).activate()
  .sort({column: spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn() + 2, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().removeDuplicates([spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn() + 2]).activate();

  //Protecting data finally
  //var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
  var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().protect().setDescription(description);
  //protection.setDomainEdit(false);   
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }      

//Removing blank spacess in between data
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
      var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
      var values = rows.getValues();
      var rowsDeleted = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var row = values[i];
        if (row[1] == '') {
          sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
          rowsDeleted++;
        }
      }   

     //For Double periods in a class
          //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          //var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
          //var source = ss.getSheetByName('yyy');
          var dataToCopyRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(); //Gets range object of all data on source sheet
          var dataToCopy = dataToCopyRng.getValues(); //Gets the values of the source range in a 2 dimensional array
          var copyToSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
          var copyData = copyToSheet.getRange(copyToSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,dataToCopy.length,dataToCopy[0].length).setValues(dataToCopy); 

      //Calculate class attendance and signed
      var height2 = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getHeight();   
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().offset(2*height2,1).activate();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(height2 + ' Students, SIGNED')
      .setTextStyle(0, 12, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setBold(true)
      .build())
      .build());
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1, 1, 6).activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#e6b8af');
      //.setBackground('#d9d9d9')            

    }    

  [dashboard][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMtHC.png
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to implement this feature yourself and where did you get stuck? Please provide your code.

Comment: Please check the codes in the post (edited). I am using StackOverflow for the first time. Note that each value in subject-code column is the sheet name (e.g. MATH4101), which I created using a trigger. Each time I add a row of data, it adds subject-code based on the sheet name. It is useful for visualisation in the Master sheet that combines all the sheets' data in one place. The data is coming from an android attendance app. If this problem is solved, it will be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the information in Dashboard contains only the subject and date? Or also the additional data that were visible in the screenshot you provided before? And do you mean by "process these specific dataset of that Sheet "? Do you want to copy data from the Dashboard sheet to the correct subject sheet (if so, how do you want to do so - when the teacher runs a custom function? And for which row? Or for the whole sheet?).? Or do you want instead to run function `AfterClass` for the correct subject sheet?  A more detailed explanation  would help to understand the issue better.

Comment: Dashboard is just a blank sheet for few visualizations. There are eight sheets (subjects) and these combined into one Master sheet and Dashboard is showing visualization from Master sheet. Only Dashboard is available to teachers, not any other subject sheets. In Dashboard there will be a menu After Class and 2-3 submenus - (i) Select the subject code (dropdown list of sheets)? (ii) Enter a date? Now when I enter a date and press OK, it will execute the AfterClass() function for the correct whole sheet and will select the correct range of data (all 6 COLs) based on input & process on that sheet

Comment: So after the function `AfterClass()` is run you want to pull the data from the specified sheet and date into dashboard? And once the function is run again (with new subject code/date) youw ant to clear Dashboard and populate it with the new data?

Comment: Please check the dashboard at the bottom of the main post (edited). Is it not possible to run AfterClass() without fetching the data to Dashboard? I mean can we do everything on the respective sheet? In the AfterClass() all the tasks - sorting, removing duplicates and protecting - need to be done on that sheet only. I think after seeing the dashboard, you can better advise how it can be implemented. Thanks

Comment: It's absolutely possible to run AfterClass() without fetching the data to Dashboard. I just do not quite understand what you want to do. You just want to run AfterClass() as it is now without having to change tabs? Right now AfterClass() just sorts data and eliminates duplicates - it has no endpoint for doing something with a date from the Dashboard.

Comment: 'You just want to run AfterClass() as it is now without having to change tabs?' - You are right. Now I am going to the specific tab and selecting all data on a particular date manually there and pressing button to execute AfterClass(). But users can only see dashboard. If we do the same thing from Dashboard, it does sort, delete on dashboard data, which is meaningless. That's why first I have to fix which tab the AfterClass() will be executed among the 08 sheets (e.g. MATH4101) and then based on the date we have to filter data on that tab and apply sorting, removing... to those data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to run your script from Dashboard after selecting the specified sheet and time

- Modify your function in a way that it takes input from the cells `A2` and `C2` and  `D2` from `Dashboard`
- Replace all instances of `getActiveSheet()` through [`getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename), whereby name is your input from `A1`
- Replace all instances of `getActiveRange()` through [`sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), whereby you define the range as as subrange as defined by the dates you retrieved
- In order to find the first occurrence of the start date and the last occurrence of the end date - use the methods [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and `lastIndexOf()`
- Make sure that your date notation in Dashboard is the same as in the sheets for correct functionality

**Sample:**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('After Class')
  .addItem('Process Data', 'AfterClass')
  .addToUi();
}

function AfterClass() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A2").getValue();
  //retrieve the start date to use as desired
  var startDate = dashboard.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();
  var endDate = dashboard.getRange("D2").getDisplayValue();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  //chose the range within the specified dates, for this first locate the date column
  var startRow = 2;
  var dateColumn = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var dates = dateColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var firstRow = dates.indexOf(startDate)+startRow;
  var lastRow = dates.lastIndexOf(endDate)+startRow;
  //now get the range between (and including) those rows
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow-firstRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  //Sorting and removing duplicates
  // You need to specify by which column you want to sort your data, in this sample it it column 3 - that it column C
  var column = 3;
  range.sort({column: column, ascending:true});
  range.removeDuplicates([column]);
  //now delete empty rows if any
  for (var i = range.getHeight(); i >= 1; i--){
    if(range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()){
      sheet.deleteRow(range.getCell(i, 1).getRow());
    }
  }
  //Protecting data 
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description)
  //protection.setDomainEdit(false);   
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

**Important**

The sample above will work if your sheet is sorted by dates (ascending) - as you specified in the comments. However, once the data is sorted by column C and not dates anymore it might not work as intended.

Sidenote:

From your code I understand that you recorded it as a macro rather than writing it from scratch (visible by the (unnecessary) calls of `activate()`).

I very much recommend you to take some time to study Apps Script in roder to understand your code in depth and be able to perform modificaitons and adjustments according to your needs.

There is the [basic tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script) for Apps Script in general, samples and explanations for [Google Sheets in specific](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and the [references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for all available Apps Script methods, whereby most methods feature a code sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. In a subject MATH4103, I have students attendance of 13 May (40 rows of data) and then same students on 18 May (37 rows of data, 3 students were absent). When I run your code on date for 18 May, it is sorting, deleting 34 data of 18 May and protecting A1:F79. It implies that datarange is working for the whole sheet data rather than data related to specific date. And the header row moves to the bottom. Please check once again.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I did not use the retrieved date object since it was not clear to me what exactly you want to do with it. Now I understand that you want apply your filter function only for rows a data range within a certain date range. To do so it is important that you specify either the entries in the sheets are already sorted by date (so all rows of interest are in an adjacent range)? Also by which column do you actually want to sort your data?

Comment: Yes, all the entries in the sheets are already sorted by date and are adjacent. I want to sort data using column C and also removing duplicates based on column C. Just now I added my complete code in the my post (edited). I will be highly obliged if you kindly help me by revising the codes above. You did more than half already.

Comment: I updated the answer implementing your request and hope that it was helpful to you. I also so that you posted your question of the last comment as a new question and answered it. This is good practice because the idea of stackoverflow is to ask one well defined and explained question per post, mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue and ask about your new issue in a new post rather than in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working - sorting, deleting and protecting working only on row1 that is header row. I understood it as I saw the protecting range as ICTE4142!A1:F1. Can I share the spreadsheet to you, so that you can test it by yourself and let me know.

Comment: Yes, this would make it easier.

Comment: Please note that there are two submenus I added to After Class menu - Single Period Class and Two Periods Class. Both are same, the only difference is, in case of two periods class I doubled the data row after sorting and removing duplicates. Both functions contains (i) sorting, (ii) removing duplicates, (iii) protecting range, (iv) calculate number of attendance with labeling and highlighted row at the end, (v) removing empty rows from the range/sheet. Please check this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ddDQPHRGR0n-rDJliaUkju3aZWW-OJ_NaVJOl1TlyF4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just had a look at your hseet and found the following issues. 1. In the screenshot provided in your question Your data (sheetname, dates) are in row 3, but in the spreadsheet your provided there are in row 3. You consequently need to update the lines `var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A2").getValue();   var startDate = dashboard.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();   var endDate = dashboard.getRange("D2").getDisplayValue();` to the actual cells containing the data.

Comment: 2. As mentioned in my answer: `Make sure that your date notation in Dashboard is the same as in the sheets for correct functionality`  If your subject sheet features the date `2020-Jun-03` - in Dashboard you should have the same and not `2020-06-03`. The reason is that the dates in the code are retrieved with [DisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). I recommend you to ivest some time to study Apps Script, so you can udnerstand the code and perform small modificaitons yourself (e.g. changing the cell from which you retrieve data).

Comment: I will check that but I used in the query dashboard.getRange("A3"), C3 and D3. That is not a issue. Probably the date format is the reason why not retrieving data. Let me check it and get back to you soon.

Comment: I checked it but without solving the last two small blocks in the original post, it is not possible to fully test the code on the students attendance data. Based on your another solutions, I modified those for manual selection yesterday and it worked fine there. But now we are taking data dynamically from the dashboard, therefore, it is really hard to modify the last two blocks in accordance to your code. Hoping your kind assistance for these two small blocks - (i) For double periods in a class and (ii) Calculate class attendance and signed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, but your newly edited code and question go much further than your initial request. Once again, in agreement with Stackoverflow good practices you should create a new post clearly definining a single issue you encounter after your own efforts to troubleshoot. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: Thanks. Probably I later added only (i) for double periods in a class but (ii) calculate class attendance and signed was there in between the codes. Only thing I did is, I dropped down these two blocks as you solved the 'removing  empty rows if any'. I hope you will reconsider at least the (ii) blocks which was there in between the codes from the beginning. Thanks for your extraordinary support and kindness. I will definitely do another post after trying myself for double periods in a class.